# Rails app can't connect to private_pub on Vagrant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vagrant, private-pub

I have a rails app that uses private_pub. Somehow I can't get my app to connect to private_pub.

Is there a way to bind private_pub to 0.0.0.0?

**Run rails server**

```
vagrant@vagrant:/vagrant$ rails s -b 0.0.0.0
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 4.2.2 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Thin web server (v1.6.2 codename Doc Brown)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
```

**Start private_pub**

```
vagrant@vagrant:/vagrant$ rackup private_pub.ru -s thin -E  production 
Thin web server (v1.6.2 codename Doc Brown)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on localhost:9292, CTRL+C to stop
```

**Chrome console log**

```
http://localhost:9292/faye/faye.js net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way, it's documented feature. From docs:

> server: The URL to use for the Faye server such as http://localhost:9292/faye.

so you can configure your `config/private_pub.yml` for the environment you need like this:

```
development:
  server: "http://0.0.0.0:9292/faye"
  secret_token: "secret"
```

Then start a server with:

```
thin -C config/private_pub.yml -p 9292 start
Using rack adapter
Thin web server (v1.6.4 codename Gob Bluth)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on 0.0.0.0:9292, CTRL+C to stop
```

I actually don't know why it doesn't catch the port number([I opened the issue in github](https://github.com/ryanb/private_pub/issues/121)), so I specified it explicitly.

Second option is to set a host for `rackup` command(since in this way it doesn't properly handle the address):

```
rackup private_pub.ru -s thin -E production -o 0.0.0.0
Thin web server (v1.6.4 codename Gob Bluth)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on 0.0.0.0:9292, CTRL+C to sto
```

You can also specify explicitly both the address and the port for `thin`(as well as for `rackup`) and omit config file at all(probably not a good idea since there are `secret_token` and `signature_expiration` options in config file which should be set):

```
thin -a 0.0.0.0 -p 9292 start
Using rack adapter
Thin web server (v1.6.4 codename Gob Bluth)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on 0.0.0.0:9292, CTRL+C to stop
```

Comment: Just run through this again. The details provided above by @rustam works pretty well. But I did encounter a faye connection refused error on the browser console. To fix this

1. set a private network ip on your Vagrant conf
2. on private_pub.rb, use the private network ip on the server config